# Java: Objects in collections

Tags: java, oop, collections

```
Vector v = new Vector();
String a = "element";
String b = "element";
v.add(a);
v.contains(b) // true
```

So my question: if the type of the elements in the `vector` are `Object` than how `contains` compare the `Object` inside with the `String` outside if `equals()` is not overriden as an `Object` I would like to know what's going on under the surface.

Comment: "under the surface" `a == b` is actually true because they are both the same string literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns `true` if this vector contains the specified element. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this vector contains at least one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

The `.equals` that ends up being called is the overridden `.equals`. The fact that the method parameter is typed with `Object` doesn't mean that the vector will use `.equals` method of the `Object` class; it will use the overridden `.equals` method if one exists (otherwise using the one inherited from `Object`). The parameter being typed `Object` just means that you can pass in anything that is an `Object` (which `String` is, since all Java classes inherit from `Object`).

Your confusion stems from the fact that the method invoked at *runtime* depends on the *actual type* of the object whose method is being invoked. Look at the JLS section on [runtime evalution of method invocations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4) for more details. You can see that it mentions a "target reference", which is the object whose method you are invoking.

Consider what would happen otherwise: behavior would change based on the type of the *method parameter*, rather than the type of the *instance*. This would completely defeat polymorphism! Consider the oft-used `Animal` example: let's say there is a single method called `makeNoise()` that returns the string `"Noise!"`. Now you have two subclasses `Dog` and `Cat` that have overridden the method to return `"Woof!"` and `"Meow!"` respectively. Let's now say you have this method:

```
public void animalNoiseMaker(Animal animal) {
    System.out.println(animal.makeNoise());
}
```

Going by your expectation, regardless of whether you passed in a `Dog` or `Cat` instance, it would call `makeNoise` on `Animal` every time and print `Noise!` because the parameter type is `Animal`. This is not very useful behavior.

Comment: and why does not need to cast the object inside as `String` ? How does the complier knows how to handle the reference inside the vector ?

Comment: The JVM knows at runtime what the target type is.

Answer (score 1):

`Vector`'s `contains` method calls `indexOf`, which compares the elements of the `Vector` with the element we are searching for using `equals`.

If `equals` is executed on an instance whose runtime type is `String` (which is the case in your code), `String`'s `equals` is executed (that's method overriding), and if the passed parameter is also a `String` and contains the same characters in the same order, it will return true.

Here's what's going "under the surface" :

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o, 0) >= 0;
}

public synchronized int indexOf(Object o, int index) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = index ; i < elementCount ; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = index ; i < elementCount ; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i])) // if the runtime type of o is String,
                                          // String's equals is executed
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Object already contains a definition for the equals method. Therefore, if the object you are calling contains on (b in this case) is of a class that does not override the equals method, it will use Object's definition of equals.

The definition of equals in Object compares the address of the two objects and returns true if they are equal. From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object) :

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

If the class overrides the equals method (as is the case for String) then the overriding version will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are using what are typically called 'raw types' for your collection.  You can add whatever you like to it, but at run time it may cause issues (type casting).  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) for a discussion